# error while seeding in database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing my first laravel project .I have created two tables in my database and trying to seed data in each tables.Data for the first table(projects ) was inserted as expected but no data has been  inserted in the second table(tasks).And when i run `php artisan db:seed command` i am getting the following error.

> "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key
>   PRIMARY

What might be the reason and how i can solve this?

Here is my extended migration class

```
public function up()
{ 
    // 
    Schema::create('projects', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->default('');            
        $table->string('slug')->default('');            
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('tasks', function(Blueprint $table) {            

       $table->increments('id');            
     //  $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned()->default(0);         
       $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');            
       $table->string('name')->default('');         
       $table->string('slug')->default('');         
       $table->boolean('completed')->default(false);            
       $table->text('description')->default('');            
       $table->timestamps();    

    });
}
```

seeder class for **projects** table

```
class projectSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
        $projects = array(
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Project 1', 'slug' => 'project-1', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Project 2', 'slug' => 'project-2', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Project 3', 'slug' => 'project-3', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]
        );

        // Uncomment the below to run the seeder
        DB::table('projects')->insert($projects);
    }
}
```

for **tasks** table:

```
    public function run()
    {
        //
           $tasks = array(
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Task 1', 'slug' => 'task-1', 'project_id' => 1, 'completed' => false, 'description' => 'My first task', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Task 2', 'slug' => 'task-2', 'project_id' => 1, 'completed' => false, 'description' => 'My first task', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Task 3', 'slug' => 'task-3', 'project_id' => 1, 'completed' => false, 'description' => 'My first task', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Task 4', 'slug' => 'task-4', 'project_id' => 1, 'completed' => true, 'description' => 'My second task', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Task 5', 'slug' => 'task-5', 'project_id' => 1, 'completed' => true, 'description' => 'My third task', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Task 6', 'slug' => 'task-6', 'project_id' => 2, 'completed' => true, 'description' => 'My fourth task', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Task 7', 'slug' => 'task-7', 'project_id' => 2, 'completed' => false, 'description' => 'My fifth task', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]
        );

        //// Uncomment the below to run the seeder
        DB::table('tasks')->insert($tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do your migrations looks like for the two tables?

Comment: extended migration class is added in the post.

Comment: You first time run the script? check table in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` column for both tables is set to **auto increment**, so just remove it from the arrays you're inserting. Because there might be other entries in the table with the same `id`, so just let MySQL handle the `id` generation.

---

If you want to make sure the tables only contain the values you want seeded, you can empty the tables in each seeding class:

```
...
DB::table('projects')->truncate();
DB::table('projects')->insert($projects);
```

and

```
...
DB::table('tasks')->truncate();
DB::table('tasks')->insert($tasks);
```

That way you're ensuring there are no older entries that can cause constraint violations because of duplicate `id` values.